# how to change button when new video scrolls up into view on page?

Tags: jquery, button, video, controls

On this page http://kimcolemanprojects.com/djangolive_1.html there are five videos.

When you click on each video the next video scrolls up into view with jQuery.

Because of this jQuery effect, I had to disable the video controls. So I decided to put a play/pause button to the left of each video.

However, I now need some help with making a script that will change the button when each new video scrolls into view. I have a piece of script that changes the titles as the different videos scroll into view, which is also on the left of each video, please see script below.

```
$(window).load(function(){
// Scroll to titles on click
$('a').on('click', function() {
var target = $(this).attr('href');
$('html,body').animate({
scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
}, 'slow');
return false;
});
// jQuery `inView`-expression
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
inView: function(el) {
var width = $(el).width(),
height = $(el).height(),
offset = $(el).offset(),
vp_dimensions = {
height: $(window).height(),
width: $(window).width()
},
y_offset = (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop),
x_offset = (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
return (
offset.top < (y_offset + vp_dimensions.height) && offset.left < (x_offset + vp_dimensions.width) && (offset.top + height) > y_offset && (offset.left + width) > x_offset);
}
});
// Change the titles on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
$('li').each(function() {
var self = $(this),
title = self.find('video').attr('title');
if (self.is(':inView')) {
$('#title').find('h2').text(title);
}
});
}).scroll();
});
```

Thanks for your time

Angela

Comment: what should the video do when scrolling down? Should it continue playing or stop? Im a bit confused because you have just one play button fixed...

Comment: there will be separate buttons for each videos. I just want the relevant button to be fixed there when the video that it operates scrolls into view. I need the video that was playing to stop as soon as the user clicks on it and it scrolls down.

Answer (score 0):

This code below achieves what I wanted and more, it not only makes the button correspond to the video that is scrolled into view, it also pauses the video when scrolling out of view and when video has finished playing it scrolls the next one up into view and plays it automatically. Thanks to jakecigar on jQuery forum.

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], { // jQuery `inView`-expression
inView: function (el) {
var width = $(el).width(),
height = $(el).height(),
offset = $(el).offset(),
vp_dimensions = {
height: $(window).height(),
width: $(window).width()
},
y_offset = (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop),
x_offset = (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
return(
offset.top < (y_offset + vp_dimensions.height) && offset.left < (x_offset + vp_dimensions.width) && (offset.top + height) > y_offset && (offset.left + width) > x_offset);
}
});
var video;
$(function (){
video=$('video:first').get(0)
$('a').on('click', function () {
var target = $(this).attr('href');
$('html,body').animate({
scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
}, 'slow')
return false;
});
$('video').on('ended',function(){
$(this).parents('a').click()
setTimeout(vidplay,1000)
})
});
$(window).scroll(function () {
$('video:not(:inView)').each(function () {
this.pause()
})
video = $('video:inView:last').get(0)
if(video) $('#title').find('h2').text(video.title)
}).scroll();
function vidplay() {
if(video.paused) {
video.play();
$('#play').text("||");
} else {
video.pause();
$('#play').text(">");
}
}
function percent(){
return (video.currentTime/video.duration*100).toFixed(0)+'%'
}
function restart() {
video.currentTime = 0;
}
function skip(value) {
video.currentTime += value;
}
```